# Knights tour dfs search with look ahead

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path, searching, knight-tours

After Using a basic depth first search I was wondering if there was any way to predict a dead end before one becomes apparent?

As I know I can stop there becoming multiple dead ends as in a single route to a square. However I was wondering if there was an algorithm or any other look ahead properties which could be implemented for a knights tour using depth first search ?

I realise that I could easily implement a heuristic version thus creating a look ahead but was more intrested if there was any other possible look ahead implementations to make for a dfs search